# How to attach databinding layout to root in android Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using databinding feature in my android app and I want to attach this layout into root in onCreate method because I am using 
Main Activity.kt fil

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<merage>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressbar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</merage>
```

How to do this using Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `activity_main.xml` then the generated class is `ActivityMainBinding`.

In the MainActivity's `onCreate()` you can do something like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

 private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main)

       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

 private lateinit var binding: ActivityTestBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

       binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_test)
       
    }
}
```